# Data type that combines properties of array and dictionary

Tags: javascript, arrays, oop, dictionary, typescript

In my project I have a collection of objects (class instances) that I need to access by key but also sort and access in given order. How should I store these objects?

I could have both Array and Dictionary and manually keep them in sync but this is suboptimal  (for instance when you want to delete an object you need to first locate it in the Array).

```
//dictionary properties
objectsDictionary[object.id] = object;

//array properties 
objectsArray.sort(function)
```

Is there a data structure that combines the properties of both Array and Dictionary? Can such structure be modulated without the need to traverse the array internally?

The language I am working in is TypeScript but the answer can be more general.

Comment: Order can only be guaranteed with arrays. You can store it in a dictionary and calculate sorted order based on keys

Comment: You've pretty much got the idea down; _Object_ of _properties_ with _keys_ - _Array_ of _keys_ with _indicies_

Comment: I don't think you will find a magic structure which has all these properties. Take a look at for example the implementation of [`Backbone.Collection`](http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html#section-116), which uses an array `this.models` and also an object for key lookup `this._byId`.

Comment: I just wanted to make sure I am not missing something big. The problem with using both array and object at the same time is as I said the ugliness of traversing the array if you want for instance remove an object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implement this yourself using a constructor like this. Note that the majority of the methods have to be defined on the *instance* because they use references that aren't shared..

```
/* OADictionary
 *     value getItemAt    , int index
 *     value getItem      , str key
 *     void  addItem      , str key, value [, int index]
 *     void  removeItemAt , int index
 *     void  removeItem   , str key
 *     void  sort         , function comparator(key_a, key_b, val_a, val_b)
 */

function OADictionary() {
    var keys = [],
        obj = {};
    this.getItemAt = function (index) {
        return obj[keys[index]];
    };
    this.getItem = function (key) {
        return obj[key];
    };
    this.addItem = function (key, val, index) {
        if (obj[key]) throw new Error('key already exists: ' + key);
        obj[key] = val;
        if (index || index === 0)
            keys.splice(index, 0, key);
        else
            keys.push(key);
    };
    this.removeItemAt = function (index) {
        delete obj[keys[index]];
        keys.splice(index, 1);
    };
    this.removeItem = function (key) {
        delete obj[key];
        keys.splice(keys.indexOf(key), 1);
    };
    this.sort = function (comparator) {
        var mComparator = function (key_a, key_b) {
            return comparator(key_a, key_b, obj[key_a], obj[key_b]);
        };
        if (comparator)
            keys.sort(mComparator);
        else
            keys.sort();
    };
}
```

Now you can create your ordered key-value pairs

```
var d = new OADictionary();
d.addItem('foo', 'bar');
d.addItem('fizz', 'buzz');
d.getItem('fizz'); // "buzz"
d.getItemAt(0);    // "bar"
d.sort();
d.getItemAt(0);    // "buzz"
```

Comment: You may want to extend this a bit more to include functions as `d.keys(); // keys`, `d.keyAt(i); // key`, `d.indexOfKey(key); // index` and `d.indexOf(val); // index (will probably require a loop)`

Answer (score 1):

In general in JavaScript, you can't combine arbitrary indexing with anything else on the same object and get predictable results. For example:

```
var arrayAndDictionary = /*... something ...*/;

// Accidently malicious user data
var objects = [{ id: 'sort' }, {id: 'length'}, {id: 'forEach' }];

objects.forEach(object => {
    arrayAndDictionary[object.id] = object;
});

objects.sort(); // Crash.
```

Really, you don't even want to key off an id unless you're 100% in control of those ids and are very careful. You can get burned by [Little Bobby Proto](http://xkcd.com/327/):

```
// Collection of users on our website
var myObjects = {};
// New user named __proto__ signs up
myObjects['__proto__'] = { 'userId': 'bobby' }
// Is there a user named 'userId' ?
alert(myObjects['userId']); // "bobby", not undefined
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try using a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) object.

You can access by key:

> The `Map` object is a simple key/value map

And also iterate with order:

> A Map object can iterate its elements in insertion order

Comment: This is EcmaScript 6, as far as I know it is not even part of TypeScript, or is it? PS: I can't wait for this!

Comment: @daniel.sedlacek No idea, I don't know typescript :)